# Capybara won't go to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm using Capybara to test a Rails app using RSpec. Calling `visit "/bars"` correctly takes me to the index page for the `bars` resource. But calling `visit "/bars/1"` (where a `bar` has been saved with `id` 1) mysteriously takes me to the index page as well, even though typing in the URL by hand works just fine.

The index page even has links to specific `bars` pages (like `"/bars/1"`), and while those links work perfectly in the browser, Capybara's `click_link` on those links takes me instead back to—you guessed it—the index page.

In both of these cases, the `show` method in the `bars` controller never even gets called when using Capybara, though it is called when I'm clicking around in the browser.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "saved it to db' and can view it in browser, it is development db. Capybara deals with test db which you probably don't have record there.

While you don't have such record and you may set 404 redirect to home, such result in Capybara is expected.

Another note, it's not good to use named id say 1 in test. There is no guarantee your last inserted record must be id 1. Better to use `bars_path @bar` or `bars_path Bar.last`

Comment: Actually, it turned out to be an unrelated code change I had made that *definitely wouldn't have any side effects.* ;) I was testing everything in test db, I was using Bar.last in my URL (1 was just for convenience), but you correctly guessed that the redirect was part of it. Marking this as correct because they're all good insights.